# Determinant and |v| being not linear

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant, nonlinear-system

a) Give an example showing that the determinant is not linear.

b) Give an example showing that |v|, the norm of a vector, is not linear.

My Work

A)
I know that for a determinant to be linear det(ka)= k*det(a).
I have a specific example that works,

B)
For the norm of a vector, I have it being linear if |kv|=|k||v|.
But I'm having problems finding a specific example that has |v| being not linear as I think it's not possible. Any tips or suggestions that may help me?

Comment: Theres more to being linear than just respecting scalar multiplication, you also have to respect vector addition. Try finding some vectors where the sum of the norms is not the norm of the sum.

Comment: Oh, right I forgot about the addition aspect. Thanks.

Comment: $\|tv\| = |t| \|v\|$, so it is not linear. The only linear function that is non negative is zero.

Comment: Having a specific example that works doesn’t prove anything. I have two examples of real numbers for which $x^2=x$, so does that mean that it’s true for all real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try a negative value for $k$.

Also remember that linearity has a second condition, that it should split over addition, so $|v + w| = |v| + |w|$.  You can find easy examples where that condition doesn't hold.

Comment: I only have to prove that either multiplication or addition doesn't hold, correct? Also I think I did a typo because k can't be negative so there should be the absolute sign for k.

Comment: Yes you only have to show that one of the two doesn't hold.  No you did not have a typo, for the norm to be linear the formula $|kv| = k|v|$ must hold (this is what you had originally and it was correct) and $k$ **is** allowed to be negative.